# URL Rewrite Multiple Params

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

I am having a problem writing a regular expression pattern for a URL Rewrite in IIS 7. I am doing the work directly in my web.config file, and the pattern I need help with is described below:

URLs incoming such as the following: `http://www.domain.com/user/<USERNAME>/subscribers`
Needs to be rewritten to the file: `http://www.domain.com/subscribers.php?u={R:1}`

Where `{R:1}` has the same meaning as it would in the web.config file, and should be equal to the `<USERNAME>` value passed in the URL.

I have been searching for a few hours today, and a few more yesterday but have found little advice on this. I am not very familiar with Regex, but have learned a lot to try to solve this, however to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

- The `<USERNAME>` value can contain any alphanumeric characters (0-9, A-Z, and a-z) as well as underscores and periods.
- I have tried a wide variety of different patterns with the rewrite module. The one I started with is this: `^user/(.+)/subscribers$`

The full block of XML for that rewrite is this:

```
<rule name="User Subscribers">
    <match url="^user/(.+)/subscribers$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="subscribers.php?u={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

That format works for the rest of the rewrites, however once I try to stick static, non-regex text after a regex pattern, I can't get it to work. The problem comes down to this: the value of `<USERNAME>` is being set to the value I want, with the `"/subscribers"` portion of the rewrite appended to the end.

Comment: Can you define `<USERNAME>`? (number of characters, what characters...). Have you tried anything with the rewrite module yet?

Comment: @cheesemacfly I will update my question with some more info on that. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Reading your last edit, I think you should use something like `^user/(.+)(/subscribers)$`, this way the `/subscribers` will be part of a `R:2` back reference instead of being at the end of `R:1` (I have no IIS access right now and can't test...)

Comment: Interesting thought @cheesemacfly. Just tried it out and it didn't work, but I do think you are in the right ballpark. I also tried `^user/(.+)/(\Qsubscribers\E)$` (to escape the entire "subscribers" string) and it didn't seem to work either.

Comment: I tried with this: http://www.regex101.com/r/xB4rS5 (note the `/` are escaped `\/`). If it doesn't work, I can try tomorrow with a computer running IIS.

Comment: @cheesemacfly Thanks for the help. I just found the (stupid) solution. Stupid on my part, that is. Thanks for all the help. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution to this problem, and it is a pretty dumb one that I should have considered earlier.

On the same `web.config` file, in the rewrites, I had a regex pattern (above the one that is the subject of this question) that has the following line of XML associated with it:

```
<match url="^user/(.*)$" />
```

Because IIS reads the web.config top-to-bottom, it was matching against the one at the top of the page (shown above) and not the one in the question, since it had already found a match.

So, for anyone in the future, write the most specific regex patterns at the top of the rewrite rules section of your web.config, then the most general to avoid this problem!

Thanks for the help!